# How does one store multiple instances of a variable of a structure in a while loop to an appendable .txt file

Tags: c++, file, creation

I am writing a simple program that stores employee info into a .txt file. It is supposed to continue writing profiles infinitely until 'n' is chosen to close file. The problem is that every time i enter in a new Emp. the previous gets overwritten, can someone help me see my oversight? Thank You in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>   // needed for exit()  
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>  // needed for formatting

using namespace std;

struct
    {
        string Names;
        string Social;
        double HourlyRate;
        double HoursWorked;
    } employee_info;

int main()
{
    char contn = 'y';
    char exitf = 'n';
  string filename = "employee_info.txt";  // initialize the filename up front
  ofstream outFile;

  outFile.open(filename.c_str());
  fstream file1;
  if (outFile.fail())
  {
    cout << "The file was not successfully opened" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  {
      string employee;
    while (contn == 'y')
    {

    cout << "Please enter Employee Name \n";
    getline (cin,employee_info.Names);
    cout << "Please enter Employee Social Security Number \n";
    getline (cin,employee_info.Social);
    cout << "Please enter Employee's Hourly Rate \n";
    cin >> employee_info.HourlyRate;
    cout << "Please enter Hours Worked \n";
    cin >> employee_info.HoursWorked;
    cout << " Enter y if you would like to enter another employee. \nEnter n to write to file. : \n ";

    cin >> contn;
    cin.ignore();

  // set the output file stream formats
  outFile << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
        << setiosflags(ios::showpoint)
        << setprecision(2);

  // send data to the file
  }

  outFile << employee_info.Names <<endl<< employee_info.Social <<endl<< employee_info.HourlyRate <<endl<< employee_info.HoursWorked << endl;
file1.open("employee_info.txt",ios::app);
  }
while (exitf == 'n')
{
  outFile.close();
  cout << "The file " << filename 
       << " has been successfully written." << endl;

  return 0;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Name your struct:

```
struct employee
{
    string Names;
    string Social;
    double HourlyRate;
    double HoursWorked;
};
```

*Then in main, make a `std::vector` of these employee structs.*

(`#include <vector>` at the top) then `std::vector<employee> empvec`

*At the top of the while loop, create a new `employee`*
`employee temp;`

*At the end of the loop, `push_back()` your new `employee` with all of the data.*
`empvec.push_back(temp)`;

Comment: ok so...struct employee
    {
        string Names;
        string Social;
        double HourlyRate;
        double HoursWorked;
    } employee_info;
then..cout << "Please enter Employee's Hourly Rate \n";
    cin >> employee_info.HourlyRate;
    cout << "Please enter Hours Worked \n";
    cin >> employee_info.HoursWorked;
    cout << " Enter y if you would like to enter another employee. \nEnter n to write to file. : \n ";
push_back() employee
    cin >> contn;
    cin.ignore();

Comment: @dhelle, no leave off the employee_info part, that was creating one instance of your struct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been at this for hours with no results.

Comment: little problem with the push_back portion, says temp undefined but at the to of the loop i entered employee temp;. There temp is underlined and says expecting a ';'?

Comment: #include <vector>

struct employee
 {

int main()
{
std::vector<employee> empvec; 
  {
employee temp;
   string employee;
 while (contn == 'y');

 {
 cout << " Enter y if you would like to enter another employee. \nEnter n to write to file. : \n ";
empvec.push_back(temp);
 cin >> contn;
 cin.ignore();
 
  // set the output file stream formats
  outFile << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
     << setiosflags(ios::showpoint)
     << setprecision(2);
  
  // send data to the file
  }sorry couldn't paste, i got it to compile but now i have only a blinking cursor at top. I'm not prompted to enter data.
}}

Comment: @dhelle `employee temp;` should be inside the while loop (it doesn't have to be, but just to keep track of everything) and the push_back done after you've entered in all of the data into temp.

Comment: (in while loop)employee temp;'expected a ";"'
 cout << "Please enter Employee Name \n";
 getline (cin,employee_info.Names);
 cout << "Please enter Employee Social Security Number \n";
 getline (cin,employee_info.Social);
 cout << "Please enter Employee's Hourly Rate \n";
 cin >> employee_info.HourlyRate;
 cout << "Please enter Hours Worked \n";
 cin >> employee_info.HoursWorked;
 cout << " Enter y if you would like to enter another employee. \nEnter n to write to file. : \n ";
 empvec.push_back(temp);
 cin >> contn;
 cin.ignore();

Comment: @dhelle  Yes, does it work? That will keep your prior employees around even after the loop has exited.

Comment: wont compile with employee temp; in the loop keeps saying expected a";"

Comment: no leave off the employee_info part, that was creating one instance of your struct...if i do that, this wont work...outFile << employee_info.Names <<endl<< employee_info.Social <<endl<< employee_info.HourlyRate <<endl<< employee_info.HoursWorked << endl;

Comment: If it's the same as your comment of 18 minutes ago, remove the semicolon after the `while (contn=='y');` <--  (also try reformatting your code because you have some extraneous braces in there)

Comment: @dhelle You are supposed to use the employee_info, use temp instead. Take the input into `temp.Names`, `temp.Social`, etc.

Comment: got it to compile but it still is only saving the last Emp I enter to the txt file. I'll keep whacking at it and read up on using vector & push_back in c++. thank you!